# Vista-alike WinForms control with a tight color bar on the left and icon and text more to the right

Tags: c#, winforms, open-source, user-controls, controls

Is there any opensource implementation of a winforms control like the one on Windows Update window where "No important updates available" or another status is displayed? It looks like a bordered bar wih a tight vertical color bar - green or red depending on the information displayed, a large icon and several lines of text more to the right.
At least what's its name?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one that I'm aware of, but it should take only a few minutes to implement yourself.

You could create a new class deriving from Control, and paint the bar using a LinearGradientBrush. The rest is just creating the labels and images, placing them, and hooking up properties.

If you aren't comfortable doing this yourself, I suggest you learn how to do it anyways and use this control as a nice, relatively easy way to learn. It'll help tremendously in the future when you will undoubtedly run into this issue again. GDI+ painting and creating custom controls are skills any WinForms developer should know.